# I need PhishTank API keys because registration for new users is temporarily disabled?

Tags: reactjs, api, developer-tools, phishing

I want to build a real-time Phishing detection application so I need API Keys.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, because of flagrant abuse of the Phishtank system, "new user" registration was removed, and will remain off for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhishTank#:~:text=In%202020%2C%20because%20of%20flagrant%20abuse%20of%20the%20Phishtank%20system%2C%20%22new%20user%22%20registration%20was%20removed%2C%20and%20will%20remain%20off%20for%20the%20foreseeable%20future.